# How to hide a running process from task manager using java?

Tags: java

I want to hide a process from task manager using java code, and tell me how to get the process id while giving the process name as input............

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is _no_ good reason to do this. The only possible reasons is to hide processes from the user. If the user shouldn't be allowed to mess with the process (say in a corporate environment) have the user run with limited privileges.

Comment: Actually I did not want to do that personally … I know there are easy ways to do that in C# ...  but I am given with the project to do that in java…

Answer (score 5):

You can not. Not in pure java to start with. See, you are limited to thejava api.

Outside java - there are ways to do that, but they involve a LOT of ground work and in general are not worth it. One approach I know of involves writing a KERNEL DRIVER - to give you an idea how low you have to go.

But again, the answer is: you dont. Not in pure java anyway.

Comment: Which is a little over the head of 90% of the java developers and - as i said - it STILL is not an easy task, rather a pretty complicated one.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't**. Java will not allow you to access system resources in way you want.
You'll need C++ / perhaps VB for that.

Purpose of Java is to build **platform independent** code. And Task manager is windows specific.

**Different languages are built for different purposes**. For System level functionality C++ is better suited. I don't think Java is the right tool for the job, even if it were possible.

Comment: @Navin Perhaps, but you are defeating the purpose of Java.